# Copy Folder Remote to Remote (No sharing path)

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

We are writing powershell script that will make backup on remote server. I am looking for some code reference that can copy my  folder from remote to remote machine . 
Trying with below sample code but "ToSession" is working with powershell 4.0.

We are writing powershell script (windows) that will run in separate server and create backup in remote machine(s).

```
Copy-Item –Path $sourcePath -Filter *.* -Recurse -Destination $targetPath -ToSession $session
```

Comment: Why not use UNC paths and [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) instead?

Comment: Agreed to what vonPryz is saying here, but you are showing code that should be fine based on what is in those variables. Yet, you are not saying if it is not working and or what errors you are seeing. Yet, again, roboycopy is purpose built for your use case and more performant.

Comment: We are getting error that  "-ToSession" option with Copy-Item command . for information we are using power shell version  4. It seems this option is not available in power shell 4 , is there any alternate available power shell 4 .